# Removing a portion of code using split function

Tags: javascript

This is the below code coming in javascript

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"
```

I want to use regex of replacing or split where I want it to be like this

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="VARCHAR"
```

The value `varchar` can be anything like integer or anything, I only want to remove `cf_sql_`

So if I use

```
var str = 'cf_sql_varchar';
var str = str.split('_')[2];
alert(str);
```

- it basically removes even the table names if they encounter underscore

Comment: The string will always be "CF_SQL_"?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `replace()` instead like :

```js
var str = 'cf_sql_varchar';
var replacement = 'cf_sql_';

console.log( str.replace(replacement , '') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this?

```js
let string = '<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"';

console.log(string.replace('CF_SQL_', ''));
```